# mysql restore specific date data from a dump file

Tags: restore, mysql-5.6, dump

I have mysql [version 5.6] database dump file. I want to restore only one day data from that dump file.

Anyone has any clue ?

Answer (score 2):

### You have two alternatives:

**1.** Load the file into a new database table and do a query for the particular date that you want.

or

**2.** Hand edit the dump file and load that (also in a new database).

### The second alternative has several disadvantages:

- hand editing is unreliable and error prone.
- you may break integrity constraints - not easy to see in a load of text!
- it's a pain in the ass :-) and will probably take you more time than alternative 1.

### Conclusion:

Load the whole file - query the data you want,

```
CREATE my_table AS SELECT * FROM main_table
WHERE the_date = date_of_interest;
```

and then put that into a separate table, and then:

```
mysqldump db_name my_table > my_table.sql
```

Et voilà!